# GL Studio 5.1 cross compiling

Tags: linux, кросс-компиляция

Интересует, возможна ли кросс-компиляция проекта созданного в GL Studio в Windows под Linux (OpenSUSE) с интрукцией что и как делать.

Comment: Ну так расскажите, какие исследования вы провели по теме, что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @0andriy пощелкал по меню/опциях.. поискал в интернете. ничего не нашел. но знаю что возможно(слышал от людей).

Comment: Попробуйте ещё раз, возможно вы неправильно задали ключевые слова в поисковой системе. Вот, например, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989431/opengl-mesa-3d-mingw объясняет немного суть кросс-компиляции в Windows для GL приложений (безотносительно к GL Studio). Вы же пока хотите, чтобы за вас кто-то что-то делал :(

Comment: @0andriy да я уже узнал у саппорта, что кросс компиляция не особо хорошо поддерживается. Установил для этого линукс и там собственно буду компилировать. Ну и я не хочу чтобы за меня делали, скорее дали совет, что для этого нужно)

Comment: @Insider **Установил для этого линукс и там собственно буду компилировать.** - ну так в чём проблема? Основной компиллятор в Linux - gcc. Если у Вас проект небольшой, то можно просто написать *gcc file1.c file2.c ... filrn.c*. Если больше - надо пользоваться make или cmake. В таком случае, придётся написать файл проекта. Это тоже - совсем несложно для не очень больших проектов.